# Deducing relations between coefficients of quadratic in a $\frac{Quadratic}{Quadratic}$ type function with extremum points given

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

A function given by $$f(x)=\frac{ax^2+2bx+c}{Ax^2+2Bx+C}$$
has points of extrema at $x=1$ and $x=-1$, such that $f(1)=2$ , $f(-1)=3$ and $f(0)=2.5$. Then prove that:
$a=2.5A$ and $A=C$
hence, that the function should be:
$$f(x)=\frac{(2.5)x^2-x+2.5}{x^2+1}$$

---

I have no idea how to start with this problem. I could understand the problem that the function would remain between 2 and 3 since they are given to be the points of extremum.

Also, since $f(0)=2.5$,  this gives $$\frac{c}{C}=2.5$$

But I'm not able to get how I'm supposed to use the given details to get idea about a, b, c, A, B and C

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this problem as follows: first, you are given the following information:

- $f'(1) = f'(-1) = 0$
- $f(1) = 2$
- $f(-1) = 3$
- $f(0) = 2.5$.

Turn each of these conditions into an equation in terms for the coefficients $a,b,c,A,B,C$ by plugging into $f(x)$. The derivative conditions will give you quadratic equations; the others are linear equations.

Now take your system of five equations (and six unknowns) and start eliminating variables. Notice that the problem statement strongly hinted to you to focus first on eliminating $b,B$, and $c$.